# Is it possible to get length of (static/dynamic) arrays from their references?

Tags: arrays, delphi, pointers

I want to pass reference of an array to a function that needs the length of array. I want to know if I have to pass its length as well or I can retrieve it from the array reference.

```
uses
  Vcl.Dialogs, System.SysUtils, System.Types;

type
  IntegerArray  = array[0..$effffff] of Integer; // defined in System
  PIntegerArray = ^IntegerArray; // defined in System

procedure Foo(const P: PIntegerArray);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(P^)));
end;

const
  A: array[0..2] of Integer = (1, 2, 3);
var
  B: TIntegerDynArray;

initialization
  Foo(@A);
  B := [4, 5, 6];
  Foo(@B[0]);
end.
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. We don't know what PIntegerArray is. What you should be doing is using open arrays.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Are you saying that I should define the parameter as an open array and pass the array itself instead of its pointer? If I get it right I must say that my problem is not about defining a parameter that accepts both static and dynamic arrays. I really need to pass the pointer.

Comment: You write "(open/static/dynamic)". There are no "open" arrays. There is the concept of an open array **parameter**, as described by LU RD below, or in [my article](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html).

Comment: And yes, you should declare the parameter as open array parameter and pass the array itself (possibly as const). In reality, this will pass **two** values: the pointer to the first element and the length minus one, i.e. the HIgh() value. If you only pass a pointer, the length is not known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question amounts to the following:

> Given the address of the first element of an array, which could be either static or dynamic, can I find the length of that array?

The answer is no. There are two factors in your way.

1. You can't tell whether the array is dynamic or static.
2. Even if you knew the array was static, you would not be able to find its length without compile time knowledge of its type.

Answer (score 8):

To accomplish this, you need to declare an [open array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters) parameter:

```
procedure Foo(const A: array of integer);
begin
  ShowMessage('Length of array:'+IntToStr(High(A)+1));
end;
```

Pass both dynamic and static arrays to the procedure, and the arrays length is given by [System.High](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.High).

> Open array : The value, of type Integer, giving the number of elements in the actual parameter, minus one.

Comment: Tkank you @LURD, but this is not the case. I just answered david's comment. I really need the parameter to be a pointer. I can edit my question to describe why If you think it makes a difference.

Comment: Unfortunately, the compiler is not clairvoyant. Passing a pointer to a static array does not pass any length information, just as David says.